# paging through database results using jquery

Tags: jquery, pagination

I'm looking for info on how difficult it will be to page through a number of results from a database using jquery. I have already found a plugin but I don't think it's what I need.

I have a form with 8 textboxes. I want to populate these 8 textboxes with the first database result and then show paging if there are more results. If there are more results then the user should be able to click the next button to have the new data imported into the textboxes.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want the next button to query the database (via ajax) for the next page or to page through results of the first query that are already in the DOM/JSON/XML somewhere?

Comment: Hi Mercilor. Thanks for the help. It really doesn't matter to me. There will never be any more than say 5 rows returned in total so I'm not that concerned about performance in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which underlying platform you are using.  It is ASP.NET MVC?  Ruby on Rails?  Paging support is generally built into the underlying platform.

If you want to make an AJAX or JSON call jQuery is certainly capable of doing that, but what that call looks like will depend on which platform you are using.

If it is Ruby, you should find some guidance here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-jquery/

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'm using PHP. The problem I see is that php requires a refresh to get the current offset and I'm stuck there. Don't have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this (or the way I do it) is that I bind ajax calls to the pagination links. The links have the url built-in and know what page they are referring to.

e.g.

```
<a class="pager" href="/ajax_pages/get_results.php?page=3"> 3 </a>
```

Now you can intercept the clicks to these links using the jquery live function

```
$(function() {
      $('a.pager').live('click',function() {
             var url = $(this).attr('href');
             $('#destination').load(url);
      }
 }
```

Since you're using 'live', you don't have to bind the newly generated HTML manually. And so your links will be ready to go right away.

Then all you have to do is generate the offset value based on the requested page and limit (which your backend service should know).

The alternative method is very close, but requires more work in javascript. Have the service that your pager calls return json encoded data. Your callback function will then have to populate your page with this data and then update your pagination links so that they work correctly.

This may be the more elegent solution than blowing out the entire form every time, but does require more work. It is unlikely that it will be a noticeable difference.

Comment: Hi Rhinosaurus. Thanks for the response. Sorry I haven't responded sooner to say thanks but I've been swamped. I will give this a whirl. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if I knew I wouldn't ever really have more than 5 pages or so, I would forgo the Ajax thing altogether... Not that I don't like it... I just don't think its necessary in this case.

```
<?php
// Example Database result (say, 2 "pages" worth)...
// We'll pretend the cells in your database match the textarea names...
$results = array(
    [0] => array(
        'textbox1'=>'abc',
        'textbox2'=>'def',
        'textbox3'=>'ghi',
        'textbox4'=>'jkl',
        'textbox5'=>'mno',
        'textbox6'=>'pqr'
        'textbox6'=>'stu'
        'textbox6'=>'vwx'
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'textbox1'=>'cba',
        'textbox2'=>'fed',
        'textbox3'=>'ihg',
        'textbox4'=>'lkj',
        'textbox5'=>'onm',
        'textbox6'=>'rqp'
        'textbox6'=>'uts'
        'textbox6'=>'xwv'
    )
)
$json_results = json_encode($results);
?>

<!-- Generate some jQuery and HTML -->
<script language="javascript">
    var pages = eval('<?=$json_results;?>');
    $(function() {
        $('.page_num').live('click',function() {
            var page = $(this).attr('rel');
            if(pages[page] && pages[page].length > 0) {
                $.each(pages[page],function(key,value) {
                    // assuming your key names are the same as the
                    // names of your textareas
                    $('textarea[name="'+key+'"]').value(value);
                });
            } else {
                alert("Oops, that page doesn't exist for some reason...");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<?php foreach($results[0] as $key=>$value): ?>
<textarea name="<?=$key?>"><?=$value;?></textarea>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div id="page_nums">
<?php for($i=1;$i<=sizeof($results)-1;$i++): ?>
<a class="page_num" href="#" rel="<?=$i;?>"><?=$i;?></a>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Kyle. Thank you very much for your response. I'm sorry I haven't had a chance to thank you sooner but I got swamped. I will try this suggestion out and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Hey Kyle, I am messing around with your example. Firstly, thanks for the code example. Since I have virtually no JQ experience what so ever, I'd like to make sure I'm understanding the code you've posted before I start investing a lot of time into it only to find out that it wouldn't do what I need it to. To me, the php array you have there.. Can you tell me exactly how this is supposed to work? I mean, I have a single html page with 8 textboxes. Each textbox has a different id. In your php array.. which is the id? The key or the value in the array?

Comment: What I need to do is to page through the different records. A single record fills all 8 textboxes. The user can then click the pageination link to go to the next record. The html textboxes shouldn't dynamically be added, only the data imported into the textboxes. Is this the way this code is supposed to work?